# Sharekit installed via cocoapods isnt sharing facebook and twitter now

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, sharekit

I have an iphone app which used sharekit and i installed using submodules according to this documentation:

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit

Twitter and Facebook sharing worked fine using this method.

Now i want to move over to cocoapods, i added this to my Podfile:

```
pod 'ShareKit/Core'
pod 'ShareKit/Facebook', '~> 2.5.6'
pod 'ShareKit/Twitter', '~> 2.5.6'
```

did a pod update and everything installed and compiled ok.

But when i do a share within the app now, it doesnt show the facebook and twitter share options.

I have sub classed DefaultSHKConfigurator and i have implemented the methods:

```
- (NSString*)appName {
    return @"XYZ App";
}

- (NSString*)appURL {
    return @"someurl";
}


- (NSNumber*)showActionSheetMoreButton {
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:false];
}

- (NSString*)twitterConsumerKey {
    return @"customerKey";
}

- (NSString*)twitterSecret {
    return @"secretKey";
}
// You need to set this if using OAuth, see note above (xAuth users can skip it)
- (NSString*)twitterCallbackUrl {
    return @"someurl/oauth";
}

- (NSString*)facebookAppId {
    return @"555555555";
}

- (NSString*)facebookLocalAppId {
    return @"lite";
}


- (NSArray*)facebookWritePermissions {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil];
}
- (NSArray*)facebookReadPermissions {
    return nil; // this is the defaul value for the SDK and will afford basic read permissions
}

- (NSArray*)defaultFavoriteURLSharers {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKMail",@"SHKTwitter",@"SHKFacebook", @"SHKTextMessage", nil];
}


- (NSArray*)defaultFavoriteImageSharers {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKMail",@"SHKTwitter",@"SHKFacebook", @"SHKTextMessage", nil];
}
- (NSArray*)defaultFavoriteTextSharers {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKMail",@"SHKTwitter",@"SHKFacebook", @"SHKTextMessage", nil];
}

- (NSNumber*)autoOrderFavoriteSharers {
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:false];
}

- (Class)SHKActionSheetSubclass {
    return NSClassFromString(@"CustomSHKActionSheet");
}

- (NSNumber*)maxFavCount {
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];
}
```

Also in my app delegate im definately calling the custom Configurator.

```
  DefaultSHKConfigurator *configurator = [[[SHKConfigurator alloc] init] autorelease];
    [SHKConfiguration sharedInstanceWithConfigurator:configurator];
```

What i have noticed from debugging is that only method: showActionSheetMoreButton is called and not any of the others.

I have also noticed that the "canShare" methods in SHKTwitter.m and SHKFacebook.m both return false. And the "canShare" methods in SHKiOSTwitter.m and SHKiOSFacebook.m are never called (these are the native versions so i guess these should be called)

Any idea why these sharers are not displaying?

Comment: If you have your own sharers.plist, add SHKiOSTwitter and SHKiOSFacebook

Comment: no i havent got that file, but i have added  the value: <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
       
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Facebook</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb[AppId]</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
      
    </array> to my  MyiPhoneApp-Info.plist as stated in docos: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit

Comment: where is the documentation on the sharers.plist file you have mentioned? i can try adding that and making sure those are there

Comment: i tried to add a sharers.plist, it didnt make a difference (i used - (NSString*)sharersPlistName {
 return @"Sharers.plist";
} in my Configurator class. What i have also noticed is that facebook sharing works if i enable the "more" - i can share from that second view screen. It just doesnt show up as default for some reason ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using *SHKFacebook* and *SHKTwitter* use ***SHKiOSFacebook*** and ***SHKiOSTwitter*** accordingly:

```
- (NSArray*)defaultFavoriteURLSharers 
{
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKiOSTwitter",@"SHKiOSFacebook", @"SHKReadItLater", nil];
}
```

Note:

If you already have used Sharekit in your app, then the `defaultFavoriteURLSharers` will not be called, since Sharekit will get them from the device preferences. In order to deal with it you have to clean your preferences (by reinstalling your app) or even you can change the key that the prefs are stored in `ShareKit/Core/SHK.m:favoritesKeyForItem` (not recommended).

Comment: i have tried this already, still cant get facebook coming up. i have noticed periodically for some reason twitter seems to show up - i dont understand why this one comes up every now and then..

Comment: clean your preferences - remove the app and reinstall it. tell us if the problem continues. because if you run it once, then it saves your favorite sharers in preferences.

Comment: Also, I don't know if you noticed, but I suggest to you SHKiOSTwitter and SHKiOSFacebook instead of SHKTwitter and SHKFacebook.

Comment: You are right! After all the struggles, this is how simple it was ... I originally set it up with the SHKTwitter and SHKFacebook and changed this over to SHKiOSTwitter and SHKIOSFacebook but it kept reading the old setting, a fresh install fixed it. Thank you sir, the bounty is yours !!

Comment: now for some reason in adhoc mode sharekit doesnt show any options !! arrrgghh

Comment: change the preferences key temporarily as shown in my edited answer. if your problem is solved then the issue is related to your preferences again.

Comment: fixed that issue just now, i had a custom plist which i deleted yesterday :) all good